# How to create a Node if it doesn't exist based on a specific property, and return existing node otherwise

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node called User, and it has two properties - id and name.  Both name and id are unique properties.  The id is generated in my code randomly when creating a new node.

What I need is a cypherquery that can allow me to check if a specific user exists by matching the 'name' field, and if already exists, to return that user.  If the user doesn't exist, I need that query to create a new node with the specified name and generate a new id to set in the node as well.

I tried using CREATE UNIQUE but I know I'm not using it the right way:

```
MATCH(u:User {name: 'John'}) 
CREATE UNIQUE (u:User {id: 'rksaxrN--', name: 'John'}) 
RETURN u;
```

Another approach I've tried is to use MERGE as follows:

```
MERGE (u:User {name: 'John'}) 
SET u.id = "rksaxrN--";
```

But in the MERGE case if the user is already found, the SET command is still executed, which means I need to specify an id even if it's an existing node.  Now, because the id is actually generated randomly, I will end up overwriting the existing id with a new id, and I don't want that.  I want to be able to set the ID only if I am creating a new node, and not otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close to getting what you seek.  You simply need to add `ON CREATE` to your `SET` statement.

```
MERGE (u:User {name: 'John'}) 
ON CREATE SET u.id = "rksaxrN--"
RETURN u;
```